# Find a real matrix with eigen vectors v and v's complex conjugate so that they have different eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

I need to find a real matrix with eigenvector v, and eigenvector v's complex conjugate, such that they will have different eigenvalue. any hints please?

Comment: We could be of more help if we knew how far you had got trying to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First write
$$
Mv=\lambda v \qquad \text{and} \qquad Mv^*=\lambda' v^*
$$
now complex conjugating the second equation and noting M is real
$$
(Mv^*=\lambda' v^*)^* \rightarrow M^*v=\lambda'^*v \rightarrow  Mv=\lambda'^*v 
$$
and finally since the eigenvalue of a given eigenvector is unique you have that
$$
\lambda = \lambda'^* \quad \text{or}\quad  \lambda^* = \lambda'
$$
so if you find a matrix with two eigenvectors one conjugate to another that's it. The most general form uf such a $2\times2$ matrix is
$$
M=R\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 0  \\
0 & \lambda^*  \\
\end{array} \right)R^{-1}
$$
where $R$ is an invertible matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix [$\pmatrix{1&1\\-1&1}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors+%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C1%7D%7D) should be one example of what you're looking for.